# DKIM Settings won't verify. SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

For some reason, I added the cnames and txt settings to my domain's (example.com) dns and I recieved an email stating that aws was not able to detect the required dns settings.

For the txt, I took the name `_amazonses.gmail.com` and added it so it looked like `_amazonses.gmail.com.mydomain.com` with the value of `randomstuffthatiwasgiven`.

For the cnames, I took the names that were like `randomstuffiwasgiven._domainkey.gmail.com` and added it to that it looked like `randomstuffiwasgiven._domainkey.gmail.com.mydomain.com` with the value of `randomstuffiwasgiven.dkim.amazonses.com`.

Did I do something wrong, or should I just retry? Thanks.

Comment: Did you specify exactly what they gave you?

Comment: Yes the entire names and values. I’m assuming this might not be correct.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Okay I tried again but I removed .gmail.com in the names (in c names and txt) for the records and I still got the email stating that the signing failed.

Comment: So then the 3 cnames had names that looked like "garbage._domainkey.mydomain.com."

Comment: Do you have long TTLS on them?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by that, so I probably do not however could you explain what you meant by that?

Comment: If you look at your records that should have a numeric value you can set for the TTL (time to live) value. This is a value of how long a client should cache the DNS value for this record. If you cannot see it in the interface of your DNS provider you can run a DIG command to see the TTL value. You can run DIG in the browser using https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig

Comment: I'm using route53 and I do not see the option to change the TTL, or any mention of it. Also I do not see the option to see the TTL value with the website that you provided.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Woops I aplogize I just found out what I'm supposed to look for "mydomain.com. 59 IN A domainip" so I'm pretty sure the TTL is 59.